# Extracting JOptionPane values from custom button grid

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

Every night my wife and I play along with Jeopardy! and I'm tired of keeping score with a pen and paper. So I'm creating a Jeopardy! with JOptionPane. My goal is to save global static int variables which contain the score and global String variables which contain the names of the players.

The code displays a window with a button grid with dollar values and with the player names. You click the dollar value and then click the name; the code should then add the selected dollar value to the selected player's score. This is my issue-- I create the button grid window just fine, but I can't get the values from the buttons. Below is my code (just up to the single jeopardy portion):

```
public class Jeopardy {

private String player1;
private String player2;

private static int player1Score = 0;
private static int player1FinalBid = 0;

private static int player2Score = 0;
private static int player2FinalBid = 0;

private static int clueValue = 0;
private static String selectedPlayer;

public void play(){

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "This... Is...\nJEOPARDY!");

    getNames();
    singleJeopardy();
    doubleJeopardy();
    finalJeopardy();
}

private void getNames(){
    player1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter the contestant names\nPlayer 1: ");
    if(player1.equals("")){
        player1 = "Player 1";
    }

    player2 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter the contestant names\nPlayer 2: ");
    if(player2.equals("")){
        player2 = "Player 2";
    }
}

private void singleJeopardy() {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
            "Get ready for the\nJeopardy round\n\nCurrent score:\n"
                    + player1 + ": $" + player1Score + "\n" + player2 + ": $"
                    + player2Score);
    JDialog dialog = null;
    JOptionPane optionPane = new JOptionPane();
    optionPane.setMessage("Single Jeopardy Round");
    optionPane.setMessageType(JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

    JPanel moneyPanel = new JPanel();
    moneyPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(5, 1));
    String[] moneyButtonText = { "$200", "$400", "$600", "$800", "$1000" };
    JButton[] moneyButtons = new JButton[moneyButtonText.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < moneyButtonText.length; i++) {
        moneyButtons[i] = new JButton(moneyButtonText[i]);
        moneyPanel.add(moneyButtons[i]);
    }

    JPanel contestantPanel = new JPanel();
    contestantPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 2));
    String[] contestantButtonText = { player1, player2 };
    JButton[] contestantButtons = new JButton[contestantButtonText.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < contestantButtonText.length; i++) {
        contestantButtons[i] = new JButton(contestantButtonText[i]);
        contestantPanel.add(contestantButtons[i]);
    }

    optionPane.setOptionType(JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION);
    optionPane.add(contestantPanel, 1);
    optionPane.add(moneyPanel, 1);
    dialog = optionPane.createDialog(null, "Jeopardy!");
    dialog.setVisible(true);

    //I need the "clueValue" variable set to the selected dollar amount.
    //I need the "selectedPlayer" variable set to the selected player.

    if(selectedPlayer.equals(player1)){
        player1Score = player1Score + clueValue;
    }else if(selectedPlayer.equals(player2)){
        player2Score = player2Score + clueValue;
    }
}
```

Any and all help would be appreciated! Once I get it all up and running I'd be glad to post the full complete code for anyone else here who would like to use it for their own purposes.

**EDIT**: Also if anyone can come up with a way in which I can have the score constantly shown in the dialog box below the player name (I realize this probably means creating a new dialog box after every click) please let me know. If it will be exceedingly difficult, I'll just print the scores to the console after every click, no big deal.

Comment: Creating a continuous stream of dialog boxes isn't really how Swing UI's are designed to be built. You should have a top level JFrame continuously present and that should be the primary UI for you app. Have a look here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toplevel.html